# Resize 8-bit image by 6x6 with ARM NEON

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I'm trying to resize (reduce) a grey 8-bit image by a factor 36=6x6. I want to use ARM NEON instructions. My code looks like the following:

```
//I deinterlace 3 8-pixel on the first line (named line0) and
//I add them. So I have resized horizontally by a factor 3
//Line 0
vld3.u8 {d0, d1, d2}, [line0]!
vaddl.u8 q3, d0, d1
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d2

vld3.u8 {d3, d4, d5}, [line0]!
vaddl.u8 q4, d3, d4
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d5


//I do this for six successive lines
//So virtually, I have reduced by a factor 3x6=18

//Line 1
vld3.u8 {d0, d1, d2}, [line1]!
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d0
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d1
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d2

vld3.u8 {d3, d4, d5}, [line1]!
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d3
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d4
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d5

.....

//Line 5
vld3.u8 {d0, d1, d2}, [line5]!
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d0
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d1
vaddw.u8 q3, q3, d2

vld3.u8 {d3, d4, d5}, [line5]!
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d3
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d4
vaddw.u8 q4, q4, d5


//At this point, I want to add two adjacent pixels
//to give my last factor by 2.
//I also want to merge two successive q registers
//In other words, I want to do the following:
/*
q5[0] = q3[0] + q3[1]
q5[1] = q3[2] + q3[3]
q5[2] = q3[4] + q3[5]
q5[3] = q3[6] + q3[7]
q5[4] = q4[0] + q4[1]
q5[5] = q4[2] + q4[3]
q5[6] = q4[4] + q3[5]
q5[7] = q4[6] + q3[7]
*/

//This code doesn't seem to work as expected...
vpaddl.u16 q3, q3
vpaddl.u16 q4, q4
vext.u16 q5, q4, q3, #4

//Now, I want to divide by 36.
//In other words, I want to do the following:
/*
d0 = q5 / 36
*/
//The best I can do is to divide by 32
vshrn.i16 d0, q3, #5
```

It seems that I have two problems: How can I add adjacent values of q registers? How can I divide by 36?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use vuzp (pretty cool!) and indeed 7/256:

```
vuzp.16 q3, q4
vadd.u16 q5, q3, q4

mov tmp, #7
vdup.u16 q6, tmp
vmulq.i16 q5, q5, q6
vshrn.i16 d0, q5, #8
```

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal addition works in general like (8 uint16 values in q0)

```
vadd.u16    d2, d0, d1 ; normally add high 4 lanes to low 4 lanes
vpadd.u16   d0, d2, d2 ; d0[0] = d2[0] + d2[1], d0[1] = d2[2] + d2[3], ...
vpadd.u16   d1, d0, d0 ; d1[0] = d0[0] + d0[1] = sum of the 8 values
```

For the specific case

```
/*
q5[0] = q3[0] + q3[1]
q5[1] = q3[2] + q3[3]
q5[2] = q3[4] + q3[5]
q5[3] = q3[6] + q3[7]
q5[4] = q4[0] + q4[1]
q5[5] = q4[2] + q4[3]
q5[6] = q4[4] + q4[5]
q5[7] = q4[6] + q4[7]
*/
```

the solution is

```
vpadd.u16    d10, d6, d7
vpadd.u16    d11, d8, d9
```

For the division discover something like 1/36 ~= 7/256  (0.0278 ~= 0.273)